# How do i make a endo like this?

Tags: materials, edit-mode, sculpting

I'm trying to make an endoskeleton for my Animatronics for my upcoming FNaF Fan game where the Animatronics are based off of memes of my choosing (Don't ask/Insult me).

I've been inspired by [this Soft Metal-like FNaF Endo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFlTf.jpg) to make the metal of my Endo look soft, yet realistic:

[image]

but I don't know if it's materials, editing, sculpting, or multiple factors.

Any tips?

Comment: Hello :). What have you tried so far, and where exactly are you stuck? This looks like a metallic shader with high roughness. What exactly are you trying to recreate? :)

Comment: The soft almost plastic like material that the metal looks like